# Postgres recursive function unique values

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, graph

I have a graph structure

```
Node(pid integer)
Neighbor(pid integer, pidn integer)
```

`Node` is trivial, and I should say that `Neighbor` stores for every node its list of Neighbors. This is the graph I am testing (contents of the `Neighbor` relation):

```
PID | PIDN
==========
1   | 2
1   | 3
2   | 1
2   | 3
2   | 4
2   | 5
3   | 1
3   | 2
4   | 2
4   | 6
5   | 2
6   | 4
```

I want to get the set of all neighbors of a node, with degree less than a fixed number, so I execute the following query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE search_graph(root, depth) AS (
        SELECT n.pidn, 1
        FROM node p, neighbor n
        WHERE p.pid = n.pid
        AND p.pid = 1
      UNION
        SELECT nxt.pidn, sg.depth + 1
        FROM neighbor nxt, search_graph sg
        WHERE sg.root = nxt.PID
        AND sg.depth < 3
)
SELECT * FROM search_graph s;
```

The starting node is 1, and the maximal depth is 3 (in case you missed them). I get the following result:

```
Node | Depth
============
2    | 1
3    | 1
1    | 2
3    | 2
4    | 2
5    | 2
2    | 2
2    | 3
3    | 3
1    | 3
4    | 3
5    | 3
6    | 3
```

because it expands all the children of each node, *including visited children*:

```
0                               1
1               2                               3
2       1    3    4    5                    1       2
3      2 3  1 2  2 6   2                   2 3   1 3 4 5
```

While it I want to *exclude visited children*, producing:

```
Node | Depth
============
2    | 1
3    | 1
4    | 2
5    | 2
6    | 3
```

I need a method to add results to search_graph ONLY IF the node was not visited.

Comment: Have you considered looking at `ltree`? It might save you a bit of pain. Another possibility may be to see if you can model this data in a form that a GiST index might be able to handle.

Comment: Spent a few minutes on this, and I don't rate the chances of being able to do this in a recursive CTE. You need a way to revisit the search_graph recursive term (`EXISTS` subquery, left anti-join, etc) to exclude already-visited nodes, and neither subqueries nor left joins are permitted on the recursive term. Nor can you use arrays to get around it easily because aggregate functions are not permitted  in the recursive term. I think you'll have to write this with recursive SQL or PL/PgSQL functions, or in the client. (Details: see deleted answer)

Comment: Well I can't see the deleted answer ... but I'm still looking for a solution using whatever means possible ... C/PgPLSQL/SQL ...

Answer (score 5):

Have you read the Postgresql documentation about [WITH RECURISVE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html)?

There are some examples with graphs and one of them looks like a solution of your problem:

> This query will loop if the link relationships contain cycles. Because we require a "depth" 
>   output, just changing UNION ALL to UNION would not eliminate the looping. Instead we need to 
>   recognize whether we have reached the same row again while following a particular path of >links. We add two columns path and cycle to the loop-prone query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE search_graph(id, link, data, depth, path, cycle) AS (
    SELECT g.id, g.link, g.data, 1,
      ARRAY[g.id],
      false
    FROM graph g
  UNION ALL
    SELECT g.id, g.link, g.data, sg.depth + 1,
      path || g.id,
      g.id = ANY(path)
    FROM graph g, search_graph sg
    WHERE g.id = sg.link AND NOT cycle
)
SELECT * FROM search_graph;
```